# 500 error code is automatically retrying express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express middleware (M1) that throws some Custom Error. When the error is thrown in M1, the error handling middleware is executed where I am setting response res.status(500).json({}).

I noticed that whenever res.status is set to 500 or other 5XX, the M1 middleware is retried 1-2 more times. When I changed res.status to 400 or some other error code (4XX), M1 middleware is not executed.

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => { // M1 middleware
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    throw new CustomError('BROKEN')
  }).catch(next)
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { // error handling middleware
  res.status(500).send('Something went wrong!')
})

app.listen(9000)
```

Does anbody knows why is this happening?

Comment: Browsers may do that for you automatically.

Comment: @CherryDT it happens with POSTMAN too. Also, only this particular middle is being retried. Others are not

Comment: What's the stack looking like during the "retries"?